# Case Expression in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have three records in a temp table below

```
 CREATE TABLE #TEMP
(
LOC VARCHAR (10),
SSN INT,
CASE_NUM INT,
INCIDENT_NUM VARCHAR(25),
PER_NUM INT,
FILE_DT DATETIME,
CREATE_DT DATETIME,
CLOSED_DT DATETIME,
CHG_CD VARCHAR (50)

)

INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES('USA','5325353','538133','USA1510000188','538395378','10/15/2015 11:10 PM','10/17/2016 05:51 AM','10/17/2016 12:00 AM','18 DEA 1324(a)(2)')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES('USA','5325353','8874353','USA1510000188','538395378','10/15/2015 11:10 PM','10/17/2016 10:59 AM','10/17/2016 12:00 AM','18 DEA 1324(a)(2)')
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES('USA','5325353','538133','USA1510000188','538395378','10/15/2015 11:10 PM','10/17/2016 05:51 AM','','18 DEA 1326(a)(2)')
```

Here is a modified code, written originally by Gurwinder Singh

```
SELECT *
FROM
(

    SELECT 
    LOC,
    INCIDENT_NUM,
    CHG_CD,
    CASE WHEN MAX(CHG_CD) OVER (PARTITION BY PER_NUM) = MIN(CHG_CD) OVER (PARTITION BY PER_NUM) THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS SAME_CHG_CD,
    CASE WHEN MAX(PER_NUM) OVER (PARTITION BY PER_NUM) = MIN(PER_NUM) OVER (PARTITION BY PER_NUM) THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS SAME_PER_NUM,
    CASE WHEN MAX(SSN) OVER (PARTITION BY PER_NUM) = MIN(SSN) OVER (PARTITION BY PER_NUM) THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS SAME_SSN,
    CASE WHEN MAX(INCIDENT_NUM) OVER (PARTITION BY PER_NUM) = MIN(INCIDENT_NUM) OVER (PARTITION BY PER_NUM) THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS SAME_INCIDENT_NUM,
    CASE WHEN MAX(FILE_DT) OVER (PARTITION BY PER_NUM) = MIN(FILE_DT) OVER (PARTITION BY PER_NUM) THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS SAME_FILE_DT,
    SSN,
    FILE_DT,
    CREATE_DT,
    CASE_NUM,
    PER_NUM,
    ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY CASE_NUM ORDER BY CASE_NUM) AS SEQ
    FROM #TEMP
)X
ORDER BY CHG_CD
```

I am anticipating the SAME_CHG_CD field should have YES, YES, NO since The CHG_CD field has 2 records with 18 DEA 1324(a)(2) and 1 record with 18 DEA 1326(a)(2).

For some reason (above my IQ), the SAME_CHG_CD field shows NO al.

Answer (score 1):

Looks fine to me ... here's a simpler query (which actually works ... what you have there won't work on Oracle that I know of:

- "#TEMP" not a valid table name
- INT  not a valid data type
- VARCHAR   that'll work, but .. well, Oracle documentation suggests using VARCHAR2 .. this has been the case for a LONG time now ..
  and your dates, with no formats, are a bug waiting to happen ..

In any case .. here's a simpler example, which .. hopefully .. shows why it's showing NO in all cases .. and why it's correct

```
  with t_temp as (
           select '538395378' per_num, to_date('15-oct-2015 23:10:00','dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') file_dt, to_date('17-oct-2016 05:51:00', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') create_dt,to_date('17-oct-2016 00:00:00','dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') closed_dt, '18 DEA 1324(a)(2)' chg_cd from dual union all
           select '538395378' per_num, to_date('15-oct-2015 23:10:00','dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') file_dt, to_date('17-oct-2016 10:59:00', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') create_dt,to_date('17-oct-2016 00:00:00','dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') closed_dt, '18 DEA 1324(a)(2)' chg_cd from dual union all
           select '538395378' per_num, to_date('15-oct-2015 23:10:00','dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') file_dt, to_date('17-oct-2016 05:51:00', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') create_dt,NULL closed_dt, '18 DEA 1326(a)(2)' chg_cd from dual
           )
  select *
    from t_temp
  /
```

This is just a simplified data set - using WITH clause to simulate your TEMP table ... and just showing the raw data I have:

```
  SQL> 

  PER_NUM   FILE_DT   CREATE_DT CLOSED_DT CHG_CD
  --------- --------- --------- --------- -----------------
  538395378 15-OCT-15 17-OCT-16 17-OCT-16 18 DEA 1324(a)(2)
  538395378 15-OCT-15 17-OCT-16 17-OCT-16 18 DEA 1324(a)(2)
  538395378 15-OCT-15 17-OCT-16           18 DEA 1326(a)(2)

  SQL>
```

And now, to  mimic your query:

```
  with t_temp as (
           select '538395378' per_num, to_date('15-oct-2015 23:10:00','dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') file_dt, to_date('17-oct-2016 05:51:00', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') create_dt,to_date('17-oct-2016 00:00:00','dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') closed_dt, '18 DEA 1324(a)(2)' chg_cd from dual union all
           select '538395378' per_num, to_date('15-oct-2015 23:10:00','dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') file_dt, to_date('17-oct-2016 10:59:00', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') create_dt,to_date('17-oct-2016 00:00:00','dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') closed_dt, '18 DEA 1324(a)(2)' chg_cd from dual union all
           select '538395378' per_num, to_date('15-oct-2015 23:10:00','dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') file_dt, to_date('17-oct-2016 05:51:00', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') create_dt,NULL closed_dt, '18 DEA 1326(a)(2)' chg_cd from dual
           )
  select MAX(CHG_CD) OVER (PARTITION BY PER_NUM)  tmax,
         MIN(CHG_CD) OVER (PARTITION BY PER_NUM)  tmin,
           CASE WHEN MAX(CHG_CD) OVER (PARTITION BY PER_NUM) = MIN(CHG_CD) OVER (PARTITION BY PER_NUM) THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS SAME_CHG_CD
    from t_temp
  /
```

we see the following:

```
  SQL>

  TMAX              TMIN              SAM
  ----------------- ----------------- ---
  18 DEA 1326(a)(2) 18 DEA 1324(a)(2) NO
  18 DEA 1326(a)(2) 18 DEA 1324(a)(2) NO
  18 DEA 1326(a)(2) 18 DEA 1324(a)(2) NO

  SQL>
```

notice the MIN for the ENTIRE group and MAX for the ENTIRE group are not the same .. FOR THE ENTIRE GROUP. :)

I suspect you may want to leverage some windowing clause .. however, it's not perfectly clear how to order your data based on the info you have given .. so here's an educated guess:
I've added a new column, simply called ID .. and numbered manually .. this is to manually , clearly .. indicate an "order" to the data. If you can logically define the order, you can simply replace the ORDER BY with your logic instead of my using ID column :)

```
  with t_temp as (
           select 1 ID, '538395378' per_num, to_date('15-oct-2015 23:10:00','dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') file_dt, to_date('17-oct-2016 05:51:00', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') create_dt,to_date('17-oct-2016 00:00:00','dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') closed_dt, '18 DEA 1324(a)(2)' chg_cd from dual union all
           select 2 ID, '538395378' per_num, to_date('15-oct-2015 23:10:00','dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') file_dt, to_date('17-oct-2016 10:59:00', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') create_dt,to_date('17-oct-2016 00:00:00','dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') closed_dt, '18 DEA 1324(a)(2)' chg_cd from dual union all
           select 3 ID, '538395378' per_num, to_date('15-oct-2015 23:10:00','dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') file_dt, to_date('17-oct-2016 05:51:00', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') create_dt,NULL closed_dt, '18 DEA 1326(a)(2)' chg_cd from dual
           )
  select MAX(CHG_CD) OVER (PARTITION BY PER_NUM order by id)  tmax,
         MIN(CHG_CD) OVER (PARTITION BY PER_NUM order by id)  tmin,
           CASE WHEN MAX(CHG_CD) OVER (PARTITION BY PER_NUM order by id) = MIN(CHG_CD) OVER (PARTITION BY PER_NUM order by id) THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS SAME_CHG_CD
    from t_temp
  /
```

and the results:

```
  SQL> 

  TMAX              TMIN              SAM
  ----------------- ----------------- ---
  18 DEA 1324(a)(2) 18 DEA 1324(a)(2) YES
  18 DEA 1324(a)(2) 18 DEA 1324(a)(2) YES
  18 DEA 1326(a)(2) 18 DEA 1324(a)(2) NO

  SQL>
```

so that uses the Windowing clause of analytics partition logic.
If it's not entirely clear what it's doing, ask away here or a new thread :)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was wondering i could use the syntax in Oracle and write it SQL server? thoughts?

Comment: Well, I believe if you keep everything ANSI standard, it should work in both .. however, keep in mind subtle differences ... such as ";" or such (I really don't know SQL server .. so can't speak of the differences, or what works, what doesn't).

Answer (score 0):

Run the following, and the answer should be pretty obvious:

```
SELECT 
    LOC,
    INCIDENT_NUM,
    CHG_CD
    , MAX(CHG_CD) OVER  (PARTITION BY PER_NUM)    MAX_CHG_CD
    , MIN(CHG_CD) OVER (PARTITION BY PER_NUM) Min_CHG_CD
    , MAX(PER_NUM) OVER (PARTITION BY PER_NUM) MAX_PER_NUM
    , MIN(PER_NUM) OVER (PARTITION BY PER_NUM) MIN_PER_NUM
    , MAX(SSN) OVER (PARTITION BY PER_NUM) MAX_SSN
    , MIN(SSN) OVER (PARTITION BY PER_NUM) MIN_SSN
    , MAX(INCIDENT_NUM) OVER (PARTITION BY PER_NUM) MAX_INCIDENT_NUM
    , MIN(INCIDENT_NUM) OVER (PARTITION BY PER_NUM) MIN_INCIDENT_NUM
    , MAX(FILE_DT) OVER (PARTITION BY PER_NUM) MAX_FILE_DT
    , MIN(FILE_DT) OVER (PARTITION BY PER_NUM) MIN_FILE_DT
    , SSN
    , FILE_DT
    , CREATE_DT
    , CASE_NUM
    , PER_NUM
    , ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY CASE_NUM ORDER BY CASE_NUM) AS SEQ
    FROM #TEMP
;
```

Comment: Thanks in advance. i will test it later. Much appreciated. Joe